# Wrong hashMap update in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashMap define as follows:

```
public class Test {
  private static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> Record = new HashMap<>();
  public static void SetRecord()
  {
    HashMap<String,Integer> inner= new HashMap<>(); 
    inner.put("CHEMISTRY", 2);
    inner.put("MATHS", 5);
    inner.put("PHYSICS", 3);

     Record.put("12/12/2016", inner);
     Record.put("3/12/2016", inner);
     Record.put("3/02/2016", inner);
  }

  public static void main(String [] args)
   {
     SetRecord();
     HashMap<String, Integer>InnerMap= new HashMap<>();
     int seatcount=0;
     seatcount= Record.get("3/02/2016").get("CHEMISTRY");
     seatcount--;

     InnerMap=Record.get("3/02/2016");

     InnerMap.put("CHEMISTRY",seatcount);

     Record.put("CHEMISTRY",InnerMap);

    System.out.println("Record: "+ Record);
    }
}
```

When I print the Record, the whole hash map is updated even if I only change the record with the key CHEMISTRY. I have this as output:

```
Record: {3/02/2016={CHEMISTRY=1, MATHS=5, PHYSICS=3}, 12/12/2016={CHEMISTRY=1, MATHS=5, PHYSICS=3}, 3/12/2016={CHEMISTRY=1, MATHS=5, PHYSICS=3}}
```

I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: What does "the whole hash map is updated" mean? Of course the hashmap gets updated if you update it.

Comment: It means that even if I only decremented the counter, of only chemistry on a specific date, chemistry has been updated on all the other dates

Answer (score 4):

That is expected , all your keys in Record map is referencing to the same map, so any change their will be reflected in all entries, what you need to do is to copy the map for each key

```
         Record.put("12/12/2016", inner);
         Record.put("3/12/2016", new HashMap<String,Integer>(inner));
         Record.put("3/02/2016", new HashMap<String,Integer>(inner));
```

Another thing its discouraged to do this

```
               HashMap<String,Integer> inner = new HashMap<>();
```

You better do this

```
                Map<String,Integer> inner = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

HashMap is an implementation, its always better to code for interfaces not implementation, this will help you keep your code maintainable, if you need to change to another implementation of map you will only need to change the class used in the initialization without worrying about how you interfaced you object in your application.

Comment: Do i do it in the main function?

Comment: Instead that asking where to put the code _try_ to understand what's happening here. Java works only by object references, you are storing the same `HashMap<K,V>`, not creating a copy of it. That's why he is suggesting you to call `.clone()` (which is discouraged in any case, use a proper copy constructor since `HashMap<K,V>` has one).

Comment: understand the concept and put it wherever you want

Comment: @Jack yeah clone is discouraged as it erases the generics, thanks for pointing that

Comment: I understand now, so if I do not want to my record to change, I have create three different objects (inner1, inner2 and inner3), add the appropriate content to each of them before putting them to Record map.